# how to use push() function for queue<pair<char,pair<int,int> > >?

Tags: stl

```
char x=ascii;
queue<pair<char,pair<int,int> > >;
q.push(x,i,j);
```

I am trying to store a character and it's address(in 2-D array).
What is the syntax to push in queue in such circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question completely. But if you are interested to **push** data in `queue<pair<char,pair<int,int> > >` , try this:

```
char x='a';
queue<pair<char,pair<int,int> > > qu;
qu.push(make_pair(x, make_pair(1,2)));
```

To understand more about `make_pair` refer to the [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) link